# How do you solve the equation $3x^2+2\sin x=2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

This seems like a simple equation to solve, but I can't find a way to do it and wolfram alpha can't give me an exact answer.

Comment: Are you allowed to use calculus for this? Or only trig?

Comment: Why do you need to solve this?

Comment: @AmeetSharma, seeing the tags for **algebra-precalculus** it seems that we can use calc as well.

Comment: the only way comes to mind is newton's method.

Answer (score 2):

This is a transcendental equation; so, you will need numerical methods and then good starting guesses.

Consider that you look for the zero's of function $f(x)=3x^2+2\sin x-2$.

For example, using Taylor series built around $x=0$
$$f(x)=-2+2 x+3 x^2-\frac{x^3}{3}+O\left(x^5\right)$$ Ignoring the term in $x^3$, solving the quadratic would give as *estimates*
$$x_1=-\frac{\sqrt{7}+1}{3} \qquad \qquad x_2=\frac{\sqrt{7}-1}{3}$$ We could solve the cubic but this is not very pleasant.

But what we can do is to take quite many terms in the series expansion and use series reversion. Looking at the values of $x_1$ and $x_2$, reasonable base points could be $-\frac \pi 3$ and $\frac  \pi 6$. This would give as *approximation*
$$x_1=-\frac{\pi }{3}+t+\frac{\left(6+\sqrt{3}\right) }{2 (2 \pi
   -1)}t^2+\frac{\left(59+18 \sqrt{3}-\pi \right) }{3 (2 \pi
   -1)^2}t^3+O\left(t^4\right)$$ where $t=\frac{\pi ^2-3 \left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)}{3(2 \pi -1)}$. Numerically, this gives $x_1\approx -1.12638$ while Newton method would give as solution $x_1= -1.12630$.

Doing the same for the second root
$$x_2=\frac{\pi }{6}+t-\frac{5 }{2 \left(\sqrt{3}+\pi \right)}t^2+\frac{\left(78+\sqrt{3}
   \pi \right) }{6 \left(\sqrt{3}+\pi \right)^2}t^3+O\left(t^4\right)$$ where $t=\frac{1-\frac{\pi ^2}{12}}{\sqrt{3}+\pi }$.  Numerically, this gives $x_2\approx 0.559374$ while Newton method would give as solution $x_2= 0.559372$.

For sure, at the price of more messy terms, we could be even much closer to the solution.

Comment: That's a great answer. I want to know exactly how you got this expansion: $$x_1=-\frac{\pi }{3}+t+\frac{\left(6+\sqrt{3}\right) }{2 (2 \pi
   -1)}t^2+\frac{\left(59+18 \sqrt{3}-\pi \right) }{3 (2 \pi
   -1)^2}t^3+O\left(t^4\right)$$ where $t=\frac{\pi ^2-3 \left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)}{3(2 \pi -1)}$. I hope you can describe it in more detail.

Comment: @PleasecorrectGrammarMistakes. Thank you. It is not so difficult : you start with the Taylor expansion and then use series reversion (google for it). Then, to make it cleaner, I change some variable. On the search bar, type *user:82404 series reversion*; you will get 153 results where I do the same. Ping me if you need more.

Answer (score 1):

#### Bisection method

$$ f= 3x^2 + 2 \sin x -2$$

We can use the bisection method for finding the root, the first is to guess an interval. I will start with an interval $[0,1]$.

Note that:

$$ f(1) = \text{positive quantity}$$

$$f(0) = \text{negative quantity}$$

Hence there must be a root or two in an interval of $[0,1]$ since there is a sign flip at the end of the interval. Now, consider the middle point of the interval which is $.5$, now the value of function at this point is given as:

$$ f(.5) = 3 (.5)^2 + 2 \sin(.5)-2 = \text{negative quantity}$$

Now, we have contracted the original interval to $[.5,1]$, now consider a new point which is the midpoint of this interval, and keep repeating that algorithm till you reach the root!